Docgen/Github installation Error in Window
Docgen
Transform your postman collection to HTML/Markdown documentation!!
i download the file .exe from binary also setup in system varibale path and restart the system so many times, and when i enter docgen in cmd ! issue occur -> 'docgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Anyone to resolve the issue????
I actually Setup docgen in system environment path varible, but not working even i restart system so many timess

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

visit this repo
https://github.com/thedevsaddam/docgen
